# Add a new gmail user via Gmail Api

Tags: java, google-api, gmail, google-oauth, gmail-api

I'm using Gmail API for Java to interact with user's Gmail box (reading emails, folders etc.)
This is how I authorize (mainly code is taken from the quickstart)

```
static GMailAuthorizationProvider getGmailProvider(String userMail) throws IOException {
    return new GMailAuthorizationProvider(userMail);
}

private GMailAuthorizationProvider(String userId) throws IOException {
    gmailService = getGmailService(userId);
    try {
        gmailService.users().getProfile(userId).execute();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        DATA_STORE_FACTORY.getDataStore("StoredCredential").delete(userId);
        throw  new IOException(e);
    }
}

private Gmail getGmailService(String id) throws IOException {
    return new Gmail.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getAuthorizedCredential(id))
                    .setApplicationName(APP_NAME)
                    .build();
}

private Credential getAuthorizedCredential(String id) throws IOException {
    InputStream in = GMailAuthorizationProvider.class.getResourceAsStream("client_secret.json");
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                    HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                    .setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
                    .setAccessType("offline")
                    .build();

    return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize(id);
}
```

A here where the problems start... When i enter empty string, the flow is:

- creating new GMailAuthorizationProvider instance
- opening default browser
- user choose or create new account in Google's view
- entered mail in my application (remember it's a empty string) and account choosed via user not equal to each other and i get an error when trying to load user information here:

`gmailService.users().getProfile(userId).execute();`

Or if I delete this line, then I still get 404 error when trying to load user's mail folders.

But if user enter something like

> username@gmail.com

and then create new account with this id, the it's OK. API pass through and I get all mail folders.

So how can I deal with empty string entered by user (which means create new account in my application)? I wanna be able to pass through API with account id that has been already created or choose in web view.

Thanks in advance.